# How to query database without models Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm new to Python and Django, and I'm wondering how you would query the database without using a model.

I have a table of ignored words, which consists of a primary key and a string of the word. How would I query in my text to "ignore" the word, if it's in the table?

All of the documentation and examples involve models, for say a Person object. But I don't know a model object for an ignored word, so it doesn't make sense.

```
def determine_important_words(original_words):
    for i, word in enumerate(original_words):
        if word[0].isupper():
            if word not in important_words:
                important_words.append(original_words[i])
    return important_words
```

The table I have is using MySQL.

Thanks!

Comment: Django is python, so you can use the mysqldb module and run your own queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing. You say you have a table with an ID and a string, but you can't make a model for an ignored word "so it doesn't make sense". Why not? What's wrong with:

```
class IgnoredWord(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Then you can simply query it as normal:

```
if not IgnoredWord.objects.filter(word=current_word).exists():
```

If you really can't do that, you can look at the very nice Django documentation for [running raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/sql/), but you shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: It was just that the examples I had found online and in books, referred to models as more of an object (coming from a Java background). It just felt a little bit overkill... but thank you! I will try your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create a simple model for your table:

```
class IgnoredWord(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Create a list containing all your ignored words:

```
ignored_words = (obj.word for obj in IgnoredWord.objects.all())
```

Use it for something:

```
result = list(set(original_words) - set(ignored_words))
```

Don't forget to run `python manage.py syncdb` after adding your new model.